# c++ multiple recursive functions

Tags: c++, function, recursion, forward-declaration

How do I use a function before it gets declared?

I have 3 functions, each one of them has to interact with each other, but I can't find a way to make the earlier declared functions to interact with the later declared functions. Here's the code:

```
int f(int a){
    if (a==0){return 1;}
    if (a==1){return 2;}
    if (a==2){return 7;}
    return 2*f(a-1)+3*f(a-2)+3*f(a-3)+6*g(a-2)+2*g(a-3)+2*h(a-2);
}

int g(int b){
    if (b==0){return 0;}
    if (b==1){return 1;}
    return f(b-1)+g(b-1)+h(b-1);
}

int h(int c){
    if (c==0){return 0;}
    if (c==1){return 1;}
    return f(c-2)+g(c-1)+g(c-2);
}
```

Comment: What you are looking for is called a "forward declaration". You will find more information in Google.

Comment: Use a forward declaration, where you declare the function without filling out its body.

Comment: Shouldn't your comments be answers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A function only needs to know another function's name, its argument types and its return type to be able to call it. It doesn't need to be fully implemented at the point where you call it. Simply *declare* your functions first and *implement* them later.

```
// Declare before use
int g(int b);
int h(int c);

// Implement here
int f(int a){
    if (a==0){return 1;}
    if (a==1){return 2;}
    if (a==2){return 7;}
    return 2*f(a-1)+3*f(a-2)+3*f(a-3)+6*g(a-2)+2*g(a-3)+2*h(a-2);
}

int g(int b){
    if (b==0){return 0;}
    if (b==1){return 1;}
    return f(b-1)+g(b-1)+h(b-1);
}

int h(int c){
    if (c==0){return 0;}
    if (c==1){return 1;}
    return f(c-2)+g(c-1)+g(c-2);
}
```